# How to remove NaN in Angular js Calculation?

Tags: angularjs

I have one simple logic for calculation but when I try to calculate, it show the `NaN`. Please give me right solution for **blank display** there

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Change the value of the input field:</p>

  <div ng-app="" ng-init="okpcs=10">
    <p>Qty for Bundle Packing :- <input type="number" ng-model="qty"></p>
    <h3> Bundles :- {{okpcs / qty}}</h3>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initially have a value for qty as well, otherwise its an empty string and returns NAN

```
  <div ng-app="" ng-init="okpcs=10;qty=10">
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Change the value of the input field:</p>

  <div ng-app="" ng-init="okpcs=10;qty=10">
    <p>Qty for Bundle Packing :- <input type="number" ng-model="qty"></p>
    <h3> Bundles : {{okpcs / qty}}</h3>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```